# How to increase the speed of my program in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, generator

I am working on a web scraping project, and I have to get links from 19062 facilities. If I use a for loop, it will take almost 3 hours to complete. I tried making a generator but failed to make any logic, and I am not sure that it can be done using a generator. So, is there any Python expert who has an idea to get what I want faster? In my code, I execute it for just 20 ids. Thanks

```py
    import requests, json
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
    
    url = 'https://hilfe.diakonie.de/hilfe-vor-ort/marker-json.php?ersteller=&kategorie=0&text=& n=55.0815&e=15.0418321&s=47.270127&w=5.8662579&zoom=20000'
    res = requests.get(url).json()
    
    url_1 = 'https://hilfe.diakonie.de/hilfe-vor-ort/info-window-html.php?id='
    
    # extracting all the id= from .json res object
    id = []
    
    for item in res['items'][0]["elements"]:
        id.append(item["id"])
    
    
    # opening a .json file and making a dict for links
    file = open('links.json', 'a')
    links = {'links': []}
    
    
    def link_parser(url, id):
        resp = requests.get(url + id).content
        soup = bs(resp, "html.parser")
        link = soup.select_one('p > a').attrs['href']
        links['links'].append(link)
    
    
    # dumping the dict into links.json file
    for item in id[:20]:
        link_parser(url_1, item)
    
    json.dump(links, file)
    file.close()
```

Comment: you could use [`yield`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-yield-keyword-instead-return-keyword-python/) and also this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

[Yield vs Return](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/difference-between-yield-and-return/#:~:text=Yield%20is%20the%20amount%20an,the%20return%20is%20backward%2Dlooking.)

Comment: @Ice Bear care to show me how because i tried it, i have never used generator for any of my program. Plus all the examples i have seen are of generating numbers, here i have to make a list of links and later request those links to get email address from those links.

Answer (score 0):

In web scraping, speed is not a good idea! You will be hitting the server numerous times a second and will most likely get blocked if you use a For Loop. A generator will not make this quicker. Ideally, you want to hit the server once and process the data locally.

If it were me, I would want to use a framework like [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) that encourages good practice and various [Spider classes](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#sitemapspider) to support standard techniques.

Comment: yeah, i just learned Beautiful soup and i was going for selenium and i also heard that scrapy is for that kind of purpose. i was just wondering if anyone knows some smart stuff to do it without it. just like i did not used selenium to get all the ids instead i used developer tools to get the header from a reponse and modified its zoom to 20,000 to get all the ids. otherwise most people would have used selenium to keep searching and clicking things on the web to get just the hrefs.